# Is it possible to exactly duplicate a paragraph in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, cross-reference

I have a document in which I'd like to make an exact copy of the conclusions in the beginning of the document, just after the abstract.

What I'd like is that if I modify the text in the original paragraph, it will be also changed in the replica, eventually updating the field such as with the ToC.

Is it possible?

I have tried the cross-reference tool, but it doesn't seem to be able to do that.

Comment: might be somehow possible wit section breaks combined with macros.
i am not sure though

Comment: You could look into mail merge, it allows you to make templates so you can auto-populate parts of documents. Not sure if this will work, it's normally use for filling in names and things like that - but you may be able to tweak it for your use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Wrap the paragraph in a bookmark of your choosing
2. Move to the location where you want the duplicate paragraph to
   appear and insert a [bookmark reference field](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/insert-a-bookmark-field-HP005187666.aspx) and enter the name of the bookmark used above.

If the paragraph is updated press CTRL+A and F9 to update the fields and the other paragraphs will automatically update to match the original paragraph content.